# Ruby- otherwise-working methods break once defined inside class

Tags: ruby

I'm playing around with a 'fluent calculator' exercise, and I've run into an issue I don't understand.  If I define some test methods independently in irb (the first chunk of code), they work, but if I define them inside of a class, I start getting NoMethodError, even though everything about the methods and what they return seems identical.  What is it about defining these methods in a class that would cause them to behave differently?

**Defined independently:**

```
1.9.3p484 :097 >   def one
1.9.3p484 :098?>       if self.is_a? String
1.9.3p484 :099?>           instance_eval "#{self} 1"
1.9.3p484 :100?>         else
1.9.3p484 :101 >             1
1.9.3p484 :102?>         end
1.9.3p484 :103?>     end
 => nil 
1.9.3p484 :104 >   def two
1.9.3p484 :105?>       if self.is_a? String
1.9.3p484 :106?>           instance_eval "#{self} 2"
1.9.3p484 :107?>         else
1.9.3p484 :108 >             2
1.9.3p484 :109?>         end
1.9.3p484 :110?>     end
 => nil 
1.9.3p484 :111 >   def plus
1.9.3p484 :112?>       "#{self} +"
1.9.3p484 :113?>     end 
 => nil 
1.9.3p484 :114 > one.class
 => Fixnum 
1.9.3p484 :115 > two.class
 => Fixnum 
1.9.3p484 :116 > plus.class
 => String 
1.9.3p484 :117 > one.plus.two
 => 3
```

**Defined inside class Calc:**

```
1.9.3p484 :024 > class Calc
1.9.3p484 :025?>     
1.9.3p484 :026 >       def one
1.9.3p484 :027?>         if self.is_a? String
1.9.3p484 :028?>             instance_eval "#{self} 1"
1.9.3p484 :029?>           else
1.9.3p484 :030 >               1
1.9.3p484 :031?>           end
1.9.3p484 :032?>       end
1.9.3p484 :033?>     
1.9.3p484 :034 >       def two
1.9.3p484 :035?>         if self.is_a? String
1.9.3p484 :036?>             instance_eval "#{self} 2"
1.9.3p484 :037?>           else
1.9.3p484 :038 >               2
1.9.3p484 :039?>           end
1.9.3p484 :040?>       end
1.9.3p484 :041?>     
1.9.3p484 :042 >       def plus
1.9.3p484 :043?>         "#{self} +"
1.9.3p484 :044?>       end      
1.9.3p484 :045?>   end
 => nil 
1.9.3p484 :046 > Calc.new.one.class
 => Fixnum 
1.9.3p484 :047 > Calc.new.two.class
 => Fixnum 
1.9.3p484 :048 > Calc.new.plus.class
 => String 
1.9.3p484 :049 > Calc.new.one.plus.two
NoMethodError: undefined method `plus' for 1:Fixnum
    from (irb):49
    from /Users/miles/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: look at `self.class`

When you define it in the global namespace you are actually defining methods on the Object class, from which all other objects inherit, so `Fixnum` and `String` inherit your new methods.  Once you put them into a class, `Fixnum` and `String` no longer have those methods defined.

Comment: I should also mention, defining things in Object is almost never a good idea in larger programs.  This puts too much extra functionality into every object, which pretty much defeats the whole purpose of objects.

Comment: Yeah, I realized I was going to have to scrap it once I read these answers.  I ended up storing all the calculation info in an instance variable and having each method return self instead of Strings or Fixnums.

Comment: That's just what I was thinking of as a solution. :)

Answer (score 2):

In the first example, you are declaring "plus" in the global namespace, so it also applicable to Fixnum. In the second example, it is declared inside the class, so it's only applicable to objects of that class. However, Fixnum is not the same as your class.

When calling `Calc.new.one`, you are getting a Fixnum (because of `one`). So you can't call `.plus` on that.

Comment: Ah-ha!  That makes so much sense now.  I'm accepting the other answer though, since it goes into a bit more detail that other people viewing the question might benefit from.

Answer (score 0):

At every point you use a period (dot `.`), you should think of what is getting returned:

`Calc.new` = a new `Calc` object (by invoking the new method on `Calc` returns a `Calc` object)

`Calc.new.one` = the `one` method called on the `Calc` object (returns a `1` which is a `Fixnum` object)

`Calc.new.one.plus` = the `plus` method called on `1` -> There is no `plus` method defined on the `1` or `Fixnum` object, so you have an `undefined method` error.